# Away3D (4.x Broomstick) - How do I set the alpha of a material loaded with a 3DS file?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, away3d

I have loaded a model using the 3DS parser that is already linked to a material and loads fine. I would like to make this model semi-transparent part of the time but not all of the time. I would like to just set alpha = .5 but when I target the materal that is not an option.

Here is the code and using:

```
        var slingPar:Max3DSParser = new Max3DSParser();
        var slingLoader:Loader3D = new Loader3D();
        sling = new ObjectContainer3D();
        slingLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.RESOURCE_COMPLETE, function(e:LoaderEvent):void
        {
            var mesh:Mesh = Mesh(sling.getChildAt(0));
            mesh.material.lights = [light1, light2, light3];
            mesh.rotationY = 180;

        });
        slingLoader.load(new URLRequest("assets/game/slingCup.3DS"),slingPar);
        sling = slingLoader;
```

I tried

```
mesh.material.alpha = .5
```

But had no luck. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I targeted the BitmapMaterial of the loaded mesh and modified from there.

```
slingLoader.addEventListener(LoaderEvent.RESOURCE_COMPLETE, function(e:LoaderEvent):void
        {
            var mesh:Mesh = Mesh(sling.getChildAt(0));
            var map:BitmapMaterial = mesh.material as BitmapMaterial;
            map.ambient = .5;
            map.specular = .5;
            map.alpha = .8;
            map.lights = [light1, light2, light3];
            map.repeat = true;
            map.smooth = true;
            map.bothSides = false;

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
var mesh:Mesh = [the mesh for changing]
for each (var item:SubMesh in mesh.subMeshes) {
item.material = null;
}
mesh.material = new ColorMaterial(0xFF00FF, ALPHA);
```